# react-native：Is it possible to keep recording video in the background？

Tags: android, react-native

I use react-native-camera recording video, but camera stop recording video when the App is in the background

Is it possible to keep recording video while the App is in the background？

Comment: Did you figure this out?

I'm also looking into this and it seems like it will be a ton of work and unlikely to even be possible on IOS

Comment: I did not manage to do it, unfortunately. But you can "save" the video when it's in the background and start it again when it's back up